# link_to helper not reaching external link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

RoR newbie and working on a pinning app similar to pinterest.

In my form_for helper I  try to link_to an external web page

```
<%= link_to @pin.url, "http://#{@pin.url}" %>
```

The web address is saved as www.xxxx so I added the http but I still get the error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/www.xxx.com"
```

and the server is trying to reach

```
localhost:3000/www.xxx.com
```

I can't seem to get rid of the local call.
I've attached both my partial form view for new and edit, and the
controller file as well.

And as a side note: since this is part of an on-line class I can't add additional gems as quick fixes for the prefix http or other versions of http etc...

Partial _form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
  <% if !@errors.nil? %>
  <div class="error">
    <label class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6"><%= pluralize(@errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this pin from being saved:</label>
    <ul>
      <% @errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><strong><%= "#{msg}" %></strong></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form_group">
  <%= form_for @pin do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pin_title" class="col-lg-1">Title</label>
    <div class="col-lg-11">
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pin_category_id" class="col-lg-1">Category</label>
    <div class="col-lg-11">
      <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pin_url" class="col-lg-1">Web Address</label>
    <div class="col-lg-11">
    <%= link_to @pin.url, "http://#{@pin.url}" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pin_slug" class="col-lg-1">Web short text</label>
    <div class="col-lg-11">
      <%= f.text_field :slug %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pin_text" class="col-lg-1">Description</label>
    <div class="col-lg-11">
      <%= f.text_field :text %>
      <%= f.text_area :body, size: "60x12" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-offset-1">
    <%= f.submit "     PIN IT        " %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>


</form>
```

Controller

```
    class PinsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

  def show
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show_by_name
    @pin = Pin.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
    render :show
  end

  def new
    @pin = Pin.new
  end



  def create
    @pin = Pin.create(pin_params)
    if @pin.valid?
        @pin.save
        redirect_to pin_path(@pin)
     else
        @errors = @pin.errors
        render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    render :edit
  end

  def update
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])

    if @pin.update_attributes(pin_params)
      redirect_to pin_path(@pin)
    else
      @errors = @pin.errors
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def pin_params
    params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :url, :slug, :text, :category_id)
  end
end
```

Index.erb

```
 <div class="header">
  <h1>Learning to Code</h1>
  <h3>A Collection of Ruby on Rails Resources for Beginners</h3>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="pins">
  <% @pins.each_slice(3) do |row| %>
    <div class="row">
      <% row.each do |pin| %>
        <div class="pin-container col-md-4">
          <div class="pin">
            <div class="pin-header row">
              <div class="logo-thumbnail col-xs-3">
                <% if pin.category.name == "rails" %>
                <%= image_tag('rails-logo-thumbnail.png')  %>
                <% elsif pin.category.name == "ruby" %>
                <%= image_tag('ruby-logo-thumbnail.png') %>
                <% end %>
             </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                  <h4>
                    <%= link_to "#{pin.title}", pin_by_name_path(slug: pin.slug) %>
                </h4>
                <%= link_to "#{pin.url}", "#{pin.url}", html_options= {target: "_blank"} %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <p class="text"><%= "#{pin.text}" %></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<hr/>
```

Comment: Did you try `<%= link_to @pin.url, @pin.url %>`? It should work.

Comment: What is the HTML generated by the helper?

Comment: Yep, that was my first attempt and it produces the exact same error and server info.  This is why I'm stumped.  I feel it's something so basic but I can't see it.  Maybe I am stating the problem incorrectly.

Comment: I've added the index.erb file if this helps.   The partial _form is called by my new and edit erb files and simply calls the form  <%= render "form" %>

Comment: Double check to see if the `pin.url` is the problem. Your original syntax with interpolation and "http://" should have worked.

Comment: Ok, newbie here, how would I check if the pin.url works?  If you mean log on to the website via Chrome etc...   that is definately working.